# In T-SQL, Why Does a Aggregate On a Subquery Run Faster

Tags: sql-server

The following 2 queries have the exact same execution plan.  They go against the same heap table that has no indexes.  I am only returning the top 5000 rows because this table is pretty huge.

Also, this table is read from 1000s of time a day and is refreshed nightly so I am pretty sure that the entire table is in memory.

**Query 1 (Standard Aggregate, ran in 1:16)**

```
SELECT TOP 5000 DB,
                SourceID,
                Date,
                Units = SUM(Units),
                WeightedUnits = SUM(WeightedUnits)
FROM   dbo.Stats_Master_Charge_Details
GROUP  BY DB,
          SourceID,
          Date
```

**Query 2 (Subquery, ran in 1:11)**

```
SELECT TOP 5000 x.DB,
                x.SourceID,
                x.Date,
                Units = SUM(x.Units),
                WeightedUnits = SUM(x.WeightedUnits)
FROM   (SELECT DB,
               SourceID,
               Date,
               Units,
               WeightedUnits
        FROM   dbo.Stats_Master_Charge_Details) x
GROUP  BY x.DB,
          x.SourceID,
          x.Date
```

Here is an image of the execution plan as well.

[image: Execution Plan]

What am I missing here?  Why would the subquery be faster?  I would imagine the exact same results.

Comment: The running times are actually pretty similar, within a margin of error of being the same running time.  Check the execution plan, but I also don't see any reason why the second version would run faster.

Comment: Try multiple tests TBH I doubt the pattern will be consistent. If it is consistent you will need to post the execution plan XML

Comment: @MartinSmith, I have tried it multiple times.  Always the same result with the subquery being faster.  I posted a link with a picture of the execution plan, but I will post the XML as well.

Comment: @MartinSmith, you read my mind.  I was struggling to figure out how to post it.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkZNwSgsU

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, they are very similar.  The execution plan looks the same to me as well.  I have tried multiple tests but the subquery has always turned out to be faster.

Comment: The plans look identical once things like query text/statement id and runtime stats are ignored. Have you tried reversing the order of execution?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes.  I thought about that too, (sorry should have mentioned all these gotchas).  Even reverse order same results

Comment: Hmmm, the overall duration is basically the duration of the sort. The sort spills but seemingly equally badly in both and the execution plan XML is identical in everything that matters

Comment: But query plans are not exactly identical - count of records accessed in intermediate steps are different, what likely makes all the difference. Does your real query not include `order by` clause either? SQL server may decide to use different subset of records then.